# How can I create multiple shades in dygraphs using a data frame?

Tags: r, r-dygraphs

I have time series data that I plotted using dygraphs. Now I want to shade some events. The start and end points of these events are stored in a data frame. However, when I try to write a function to add multiple shades, I always get error messages.

I have tried using a for loop directly in the code, but then I get the error message that my dummy variable can't be found.
I have tried writing a function with a for loop, but somehow when I apply it, the first argument it uses is ".". Which of course messes up the function.

```
for (i in 1:length(dataframe$start)){
dyShading(from = dataframe$start[i], to = dataframe$end[i])
}
```

```
addshading <- function(periods){
  for (i in 1:length(periods[,1])){
    x <-dyShading(from = periods$start[i], to = periods$end[i])
  }
  x
}
```

Running the for loop directly after `dygraph() %>%` gives the following error message:

> Error in function_list[k] : object 'i' not found

Running `addshading(dataframe)` directly after `dygraph() %>%` gives the following error message:

> Error in addshading(., dataframe) : unused argument (dataframe)

I hope I made myself clear, I am new to ask for help with coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign `dygraph()` to an object first and then incrementally update that object with `dyShading()` -

```
p <- dygraph(your_data)

for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe)) {
  p <- p %>% dyShading(from = dataframe$start[i], to = dataframe$end[i])
}

print(p)
```

Comment: Any idea on how can we do this with `purrr` package?